# Teradata Error: The pattern specified is not a valid pattern

Tags: regex, teradata

I am trying to query a column that contains a 6 digit number. For example, if this is my dataset then row 1 and 3 contain a 6 digit number.

```
row column_name
1   ID 784651
2   work ID
3   L873009
```

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR("column_name", '([0-9]){6,}')
```

I thought the above line would work but I get an error that says

> The pattern specified is not a valid pattern.

How do I query for any six digit number in a column?

Comment: What if you try with `[0-9]{6,}`?

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the error.

Comment: What's your TD release? This should work as-is.

Comment: @dnoeth Teradata Release 15.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[0-9]{6}` instead of `([0-9]){6,}`